# Electron - Uncaught Error: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have added an event listener to my electron's main.js:

```
document.getElementById("btnEd").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    console.log('button was clicked');
});
```

The problem is that I keep getting this error:

Uncaught Error: document is not defined

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You can not do this on main process

> In Electron, the process that runs package.json's main script is
>   called the main process. The script that runs in the main process can
>   display a GUI by creating web pages. An Electron app always has one
>   main process, but never more.

You should take a look at Electron Application Architecture fisrt: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture